# Spring Hateoas: EntityModel _links rendered before content

Tags: spring-restcontroller, spring-hateoas

This is a weird problem to describe since it's no actually a problem in the technical sense but still makes me curious enough to ask about it:

I created a `@RestController` that returns `ResponseEntity<EntityModel<?>>`. I build the `EntityModel` and attach a self link built with `linkTo` and `methodOn`. Now for some reason, the output looks like this:

```
{
  "_links" : {
    "self" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/points/knx/office_light"
    }
  },
  "labels" : {
    "name" : "Light",
    "room" : "Office"
  },
  "access" : [ "READ", "WRITE" ],
  "type" : "SwitchPoint",
  "state" : "OFF"
}
```

Contrary to other rest services I have build, the "_link" gets rendered at the top not at the bottom. Any ideas why?

```
@GetMapping("{ext}/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<EntityModel<Map<String, Object>>> oneByExt(@PathVariable String ext,
        @PathVariable String id) {
    EntityModel<Map<String, Object>> point = client.getPoint(ext, id);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(localToGlobal(ext, point), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

```
private <T> EntityModel<T> localToGlobal(String ext, EntityModel<T> model) {
    ComposedId id = ComposedId.fromEntityModel(ext, model);

    Link newSelfLink = linkTo(methodOn(PointController.class).oneByExt(id.getExtension(), id.getIdentifier()))
            .withSelfRel();

    EntityModel<T> newModel = EntityModel.of(model.getContent());
    newModel.add(newSelfLink);
    return newModel;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably due to the Map, I'm assuming you using something like HashMap which has no guarantee of iteration order.  Try change it to a LinkedHashMap and see what happens (should print the values in the order they were added to the map)

Comment: I checked every java.util.Map I was using in the "client" and the controller and changed everything explicitly to "LinkedHashMap". The order is still the same. I debugged at different steps of the process and the return value of "localToGlobal" returns a proper EntityModel with "content" in the original order. Since "_links" is not part of that map anyway, the serializer must be the one deciding to put _links at the front.